# How to add an action on workflow created button in NetSuite

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I want to send an email on button click in SuiteScript 2.0, but the button to send email is created using workflow, I tried using clientScript but clientScript only seems to be working when it is edit mode, how can I perform this task in view mode ? reading the help on NetSuite I found out that we can do this in Workflow Action Script but I can't really understand this. Please any help would be really useful.

Comment: Regarding the workflow action scripts I would need a more specific answer
You can load a client script to a form on VIEW through a user event using the form.clientScriptModulePath function. 
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4625445350.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a script. I've done this in a straight workflow.

1. Create the button in state 1
2. Create state 2
3. Create Transition using the "Execute on Button" trigger
4. Add email action in state two On Entry.

That's it.